# How can i create regular remainder mail to Regular Customer about Remainder Mail Automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, email, adminnotification

I need to configure `remainder messages to regular customer`,

eg:: If a customer purchased every month, i need to send this remainder mail: `This is the time for your order.`

Answer (score 1):

> You will have to write a `custom module` to achieve this.You gonna
>   need `Cron Job` to send mails periodically.

This example might help you.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <inchoo_orderreminder>
                <!-- Daily at 1 am -->
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>inchoo_orderreminder/observer::processOrderReminders</model></run>
            </inchoo_orderreminder>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Here’s the code snippet of class Inchoo_OrderReminder_Model_Observer’s protected function for sending transactional emails:

> ```
> /**
>  * Send transactional emails.
>  * 
>  * @param Varien_Object $customer Customer object
>  * @param int $reminderLimit Number of days for last reminder
>  * @param int $reminderKey Number of days since customer account was created
>  * @param string $template Email template
>  */
> protected function _sendOrderReminderEmail(Varien_Object $customer, $reminderLimit, $reminderKey, $template)
> {
>     $this->_log('Preparing email...');
>
>     // Get necessary vars
>     $copyTo = $this->_getStoreConfigCopyTo();
>     $copyMethod = $this->_getStoreConfigCopyMethod();
>     $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
>
>     // Uses code from Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()
>     $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
>     $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
>     $emailInfo->addTo($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getName());
>     if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
>         // Add bcc to customer email
>         foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
>             $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
>
>             $this->_log(sprintf('Add %s to Bcc.', $email));
>         }
>     }
>     $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
>
>     // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
>     if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
>         foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
>             $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
>             $emailInfo->addTo($email);
>             $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
>
>             $this->_log(sprintf('Will send a copy to  %s.', $email));
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Set all required params and send emails
>     $mailer->setSender($this->_getStoreConfigIdentity(), $storeId);
>     $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
>     $mailer->setTemplateId($template);
>     $mailer->setTemplateParams(
>         array(
>             // Customer object
>             'customer' => $customer,
>
>             // Reminder for number of days
>             'reminder_days' => $reminderKey,
>
>             // Last reminder number of days
>             'reminder_limit' => $reminderLimit
>         )
>     );
>
>     // Send
>     $mailer->send();
>
>     $this->_log('Email sent.');
> }
> ```

Please refer to the link below for more info.

http://inchoo.net/magento/remind-customers-to-place-their-first-order-in-magento/

Comment: How can i use  * Send transactional emails. code

Comment: Does it manual code run every time

Comment: once you setup the cron it will run automatically. you can see it in cron_schedule table of magento.

Comment: you will have to override core class to send custom transactional emails

Comment: Am just download and move to my root folder, and my result is

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9ndHpqz.png

Comment: does it enough, or what i do next

Comment: yeah i think it will work.. screen shot looks fine to me... if you want to test it try to execute cron from the terminal. and check changes in cron_schedule table... you can even write a shell to execute cron from the terminal.. there are lot of tutorials available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44786/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-bilal).

Comment: @ chat  : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44786/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-bilal

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44786/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-bilal

Comment: @ Bilal : Remainder messages not sent, could you pls come to chat

Comment: Not working....